# jQuery resizable() "Containment" Parameter Not Accepting Array

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, draggable, resizable

Here's the basic code:

```
$('#some_selector').resizable({
    handles: "e",
    containment: [250, 0, 0, 0]
 });
```

Based on everything I'm reading, this should work. But instead I'm getting a "Cannot read property 'defaultView' of undefined' error. If I pass the containment parameter a value of "parent," everything works fine. It's just when I try to pass it an array do things break down.

Not sure if it's relevant, but the resizable div is absolutely positioned.

Comment: The documentation doesn't seem to suggest that an array is a valid value for containment, just element/selector/parent/document, where are you reading that it is?

Answer (score 0):

You cant use an array on cantainment value. You have to create a parent for $('#some_selector'), and give it width of 250px. Then use resizable in that way:

$('#some_selector').resizable({
    "handles": "e",
    "containment": "parent"
 });

Meaby you can apply position absolute to the parent... i dont know. I need more information.